# c# The term 'Enable-Mailbox' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell

All is working well on developer's computer from VS or from bin/release files of wpf app. But, when I run the same project from VS or bin/release files on another computer I'm receiving an error:"The term 'Enable-Mailbox' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again." 
Here is the code where the error is happening:

```
    public static class  ManageMailBox
{
    public static bool CreateMailBox(string strUserID, string admin_user, string pword) //, string str_upn)
    {
        try
        {
            string strExchangeServer = Constants.ExchangeServer; 
            Uri uri = new Uri(@"http://" + strExchangeServer + @"/powershell?serializationLevel=Full"); // orig works

            /// must pass secure string
            char[] passwordChars = pword.ToCharArray();
            SecureString password = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in passwordChars)
            {
                password.AppendChar(c);
            }
            PSCredential credential = new PSCredential("DOMAIN\\" + admin_user, password);
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
            PSCommand command = new PSCommand();

            command.AddCommand("New-PSSession");
            command.AddParameter("ConfigurationName", "Microsoft.Exchange");
            command.AddParameter("ConnectionUri", uri);
            command.AddParameter("Credential", credential);
            command.AddParameter("Authentication", "Default");
            PSSessionOption sessionOption = new PSSessionOption();
            sessionOption.SkipCACheck = true;
            sessionOption.SkipCNCheck = true;
            sessionOption.SkipRevocationCheck = true;
            command.AddParameter("SessionOption", sessionOption);

            powershell.Commands = command;
            try
            {
                // open the remote runspace
                runspace.Open();

                // associate the runspace with powershell
                powershell.Runspace = runspace;

                // invoke the powershell to obtain the results
                Collection<PSSession> result = powershell.Invoke<PSSession>();

                foreach (ErrorRecord current in powershell.Streams.Error)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Exception: " + current.Exception.ToString());
                    throw new Exception("Inner Exception: " + current.Exception.InnerException);
                }

                if (result.Count != 1)
                    throw new Exception("Unexpected number of Remote Runspace connections returned.");

                // Set the runspace as a local variable on the runspace
                powershell = PowerShell.Create();
                command = new PSCommand();
                command.AddCommand("Set-Variable");
                command.AddParameter("Name", "ra");
                command.AddParameter("Value", result[0]);
                powershell.Commands = command;
                powershell.Runspace = runspace;

                powershell.Invoke();

                // First import the cmdlets in the current runspace (using Import-PSSession)
                powershell = PowerShell.Create();
                command = new PSCommand();
                //command.AddScript("Set-ExecutionPolicy -Unrestricted");
                command.AddScript("Import-PSSession -Session $ra");
                powershell.Commands = command;
                powershell.Runspace = runspace;
                powershell.Invoke();

                // Now run get-ExchangeServer
                powershell = PowerShell.Create();
                command = new PSCommand();

                command.AddCommand("Enable-Mailbox");
                command.AddParameter("Identity", strUserID);
                command.AddParameter("Alias", strUserID);
                command.AddParameter("Database", "IAP Mailbox Database 0948752629");
                powershell.Commands = command;
                powershell.Runspace = runspace;
                powershell.Invoke(); // ERROR !!! The term 'Enable-Mailbox' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function

                return true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex) { 
                    throw new Exception(ex.Message.ToString()); }
            finally
            {
                // dispose the runspace and enable garbage collection
                runspace.Dispose();
                runspace = null;

                // Finally dispose the powershell and set all variables to null to free
                // up any resources.
                powershell.Dispose();
                powershell = null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception argex)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(argex.Message.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Install the Exchange PowerShell module on your computer. Also see what other software is installed on their machine that isn't on yours. Better yet: get them to **document the dependencies, environment and on-boarding instructions!**

Comment: On my (developer) computer all is working well. So, it seems as I don't need any additional installations there. There is an extension dll however that is System.Management.Automation.dll that I placed into the project lib folder that I created inside the project in VS and made Local=true for it. I added the hint path into config as ../lib/System.Management.Automation.dll  as well. But, when I use the same project files in VS on another computer that was said has the same configuration the code is going Ok but till that line where it's generating the error.